# BorderLayout container size probleme

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt, gxt, border-layout

I'm using GWT and GXT. I would like to make a BorderLayout.

### Example by Sencha

The example Borderlayout on the Sencha site looks like this:
[image]
This is from the original Sencha GXT site. It's an example application with source code:
[enter link description here](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:borderlayout(uibinder))

### My example

I made an example project with this source code. But it looks like this:
[image]

### My problem

My problem is that I would like to see the **North container to fill the available space**. Currently it appear just the header of the North container.

My souce code is the same like at the sencha site.

How can I achive that?

---

### Source code

**BorderLayoutUiBinderExample.java:**

```
package com.ex.borderlayout.client;


import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.IsWidget;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
import com.sencha.gxt.core.client.Style.LayoutRegion;
import com.sencha.gxt.core.client.util.Margins;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.Component;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.button.TextButton;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.BorderLayoutContainer;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.BorderLayoutContainer.BorderLayoutData;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.MarginData;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.event.SelectEvent;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.event.SelectEvent.SelectHandler;



public class BorderLayoutUiBinderExample implements IsWidget, EntryPoint {

      private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);      
      interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, BorderLayoutUiBinderExample> {}


      @UiField(provided = true)
      MarginData outerData = new MarginData(10);
      @UiField(provided = true)
      BorderLayoutData northData = new BorderLayoutData(100);
      @UiField(provided = true)
      BorderLayoutData westData = new BorderLayoutData(150);
      @UiField(provided = true)
      MarginData centerData = new MarginData();
      @UiField(provided = true)
      BorderLayoutData eastData = new BorderLayoutData(150);
      @UiField(provided = true)
      BorderLayoutData southData = new BorderLayoutData(100);
      @UiField
      BorderLayoutContainer con;
      @UiField
      FlexTable table;


      private Widget widget;

      public Widget asWidget() {
        if (widget == null) {
          northData.setMargins(new Margins(5));
          westData.setMargins(new Margins(0, 5, 0, 5));
          westData.setCollapsible(true);
          westData.setSplit(true);
          eastData.setMargins(new Margins(0, 5, 0, 5));
          southData.setMargins(new Margins(5));

          widget = uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);

          for (int i = 0; i < LayoutRegion.values().length; i++) {
            final LayoutRegion r = LayoutRegion.values()[i];
            if (r == LayoutRegion.CENTER) {
              continue;
            }

            SelectHandler handler = new SelectHandler() {
              @Override
              public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
                TextButton btn = (TextButton) event.getSource();
                String txt = btn.getText();
                if (txt.equals("Expand")) {
                  con.expand(r);
                } else if (txt.equals("Collapse")) {
                  con.collapse(r);
                } else if (txt.equals("Show")) {
                  con.show(r);
                } else {
                  con.hide(r);
                }
              }
            };

            table.setHTML(i, 0, "<div style='font-size: 12px; width: 100px'>" + r.name() + ":</span>");
            table.setWidget(i, 1, new TextButton("Expand", handler));
            table.setWidget(i, 2, new TextButton("Collapse", handler));
            table.setWidget(i, 3, new TextButton("Show", handler));
            table.setWidget(i, 4, new TextButton("Hide", handler));

          }
        }

        return widget;
      }

      public void onModuleLoad() {
        RootPanel.get().add(asWidget());
      }

    }
```

**BorderLayoutUiBinderExample.ui.xml:**

```
<!--

    Sencha GXT 3.1.2 - Sencha for GWT
    Copyright(c) 2007-2014, Sencha, Inc.
    licensing@sencha.com

    http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/license/

-->
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
    xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:container="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container"
    xmlns:gxt="urn:import:com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client">

  <ui:style>
    .centerMargin {
        margin: 10px;
    }
  </ui:style>

  <ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.MarginData" field="outerData" />
  <ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.BorderLayoutContainer.BorderLayoutData" field="northData" />
  <ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.BorderLayoutContainer.BorderLayoutData" field="westData" />
  <ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.MarginData" field="centerData" />
  <ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.BorderLayoutContainer.BorderLayoutData" field="eastData" />
  <ui:with type="com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.BorderLayoutContainer.BorderLayoutData" field="southData" />

  <container:SimpleContainer>
    <container:child layoutData="{outerData}">
      <container:BorderLayoutContainer ui:field="con" borders="true">

        <container:north layoutData="{northData}">
          <gxt:ContentPanel />
        </container:north>

        <container:west layoutData="{westData}">
          <gxt:ContentPanel />
        </container:west>

        <container:center layoutData="{centerData}">
          <gxt:ContentPanel headingText="BorderLayout UiBinder Example" resize="false">
            <g:FlexTable ui:field="table" addStyleNames="{style.centerMargin}" cellSpacing="8" cellPadding="4" />
          </gxt:ContentPanel>
        </container:center>

        <container:east layoutData="{eastData}">
          <gxt:ContentPanel />
        </container:east>

        <container:south layoutData="{southData}">
          <gxt:ContentPanel />
        </container:south>

      </container:BorderLayoutContainer>
    </container:child>
  </container:SimpleContainer>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Neptune theme working, add:

```
<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.theme.neptune.Theme' />
```

to your module descriptor.

Create a ViewPort and add the it with `RootLayoutPanel.get().add(vp)`.

Add your widget to the viewport:

```
   public void onModuleLoad() {
        Viewport vp = new Viewport();
        vp.add(asWidget());
        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(vp);
    }
```

This will create a BorderLayoutContainer similar to the one of the Sencha example.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! That's working! And it's look like a very useful solution. ViewPort can be resize automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to divide the layout into two areas, you will need to use only two containers - `center` and `south`.

For example,

```
<container:SimpleContainer>
    <container:child layoutData="{outerData}">
      <container:BorderLayoutContainer ui:field="con">

        <container:center layoutData="{centerData}">
          <gxt:ContentPanel>
            <g:FlexTable ui:field="table"/>
          </gxt:ContentPanel>
        </container:center>

        <container:south layoutData="{southData}">
          <gxt:ContentPanel />
        </container:south>

      </container:BorderLayoutContainer>
    </container:child>
</container:SimpleContainer>
```

Comment: Ok, thx! But this isn't my problem. I want the north container fill the available space like the sencha site